# How to account for localStorage's size limits

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage, session-storage

I have a Web app that contains a large grid of results. I'd like to store these results in the browser's localStorage for quick retrieval.

However, after about ten searches, localStorage will hit its size limit (which is about 5 MB or so, depending on the brand of browser). I'm wondering what possible negative effects could occur at that point . . .

Will the browser discard older stored items as new ones are added (this is what I'm hoping for)? Will it not store new results without me manually removing old ones? Or will the browser throw an exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"[...] changes to the data storage area must either be successful, or the data storage area must not be changed at all."

And a `QuotaExceededError` is thrown, all specified here: http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/#the-storage-interface

Comment: So, for my purposes, I will clear the localStorage if I catch that exception in a try-catch block. Thanks.

Comment: You should also implement logic in case the user has disabled the storage for the site, don't want to get someone stuck in an infinite loop of trying to free up memory that will never exist.